# What is my DNS mis-configuration in docker?

Tags: networking, configuration, dns, proxy, docker

I recently installed docker on my ubuntu 16.04. I  pulled and run  hello-world, ubuntu  and sinatra images sucessfully, but they cannot connect to the internet I think!!

Example the following errors are thrown

***1. In ubuntu image :***

```
 ali@ali-Satellite-M645:~$ sudo docker run ubuntu apt-get update


  Err:1 `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease`
   Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

 Err:2 `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates` InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

 Err:3 `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security` InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

 Reading package lists...

 W: Failed to fetch `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease`  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

 W: Failed to fetch `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease`  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

 W: Failed to fetch `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease`  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

 W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

***2. And this on sinatra***

```
   ali@ali-Satellite-M645:~$ docker run -i -t  training/sinatra


   root@fd5c3656dd0b:/# ping google.com
   ping: unknown host google.com
   root@fd5c3656dd0b:/#
```

---

So I googled for this, people are talking about a **DNS configuration problem** which makes image unable to resolve the domain name.

The solution for such problem is to change edit the file /etc/default/docker and put a correct available DNS ip so:

1. grabbed the DNS ips using network manager :

   ```
   nmcli dev show | grep DNS | sed 's/\s\s*/\t/g' | cut -f 2
   ```

Took the DNS ips : 10.10.10.11 and  10.10.10.10

2. Edited the file to be like so:

   ```
     # Docker Upstart and SysVinit configuration file  
     #
     # THIS FILE DOES NOT APPLY TO SYSTEMD
     #
     #   Please see the documentation for "systemd drop-ins":
     #   https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/systemd/

     # Customize location of Docker binary (especially for development testing).
     #DOCKER="/usr/local/bin/docker"
     # Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
     DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 10.10.10.11 --dns 10.10.10.10 --dns 8.8.8.8"

     # If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be  specified here.
     #export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"

     # This is also a handy place to tweak where Docker's temporary files go.
     #export TMPDIR="/mnt/bigdrive/docker-tmp"
   ```
3. Restarted Docker

   ```
      sudo service docker restart
   ```
4. retried apt-get update on ubuntu image and ping google.com the same errors are thrown

Any idea for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is correct way to fix name resolution from Docker container?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162163/what-is-correct-way-to-fix-name-resolution-from-docker-container)

Comment: What does the output of `sudo docker run ubuntu cat /etc/resolv.conf` look like? Are the DNS servers you configured actually being used inside the container?